ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bspline'
Even though i definitely have installed bspline, i can not import it.
I both tried it in Pycharm with different interpreters and in Jupiter through anaconda.

`!pip install bspline
import bspline
import bspline.splinelab as splinelab

Requirement already satisfied: bspline in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from bspline) (1.26.4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/tp/60lrqd_s00n2_pltpq25by680000gn/T/ipykernel_11676/2406781304.py in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install bspline')
----> 2 import bspline
      3 import bspline.splinelab as splinelab
      4 
      5 X_min = np.min(np.min(X))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bspline


Welcome! Did you restart your kernal after pip install ?

This is most likely happening because you are using a python interpreter from a different location than your pip. You need to install with pip from the same environment as the python you are using.
So install it using "python -m pip install bspline"
Then run your script with "python script_name.py"
Replace "script_name.py" with the actual python file name you want to run.

If your on Linux, try to create a separate environment:
pyhton3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install bspline

